# Error with Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I have this error with Firebase in Android Studio and I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me?

Here is the error:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\kites\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  C:\Users\kites\AndroidStudioProjects\60degree\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\kites\AndroidStudioProjects\60degree\app\google-services.json

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.148 secs
```

Comment: `File google-services.json is missing`... Go read the documentation again from the beginning

Comment: google-services.json information can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase